# Fish and Bash cross-platform variable expansion

Tags: bash, fish

I’ve got this script in my `package.json` that takes env var as a param:

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "./bin/foo-script.sh ${BAR}",
}
```

Fish naturally throws an error `fish: Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use {$BAR}.`

I thought it would work if I’d call it with `bash -c`:

```
"foo": "bash -c ./bin/foo-script.sh ${BAR}"
```

But it does not, same error.

Multiple people need to use the `package.json`, so it would need to work in both Fish and Bash.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `$BAR`:

```
"scripts": {
   "foo": "./bin/foo-script.sh $BAR",
}
```

The `${BAR}` form has no quoting function, it's purely to separate the variable name from surrounding strings (e.g. things like `${HOME}foo` - `$HOMEfoo` would expand a variable by the name of "HOMEfoo").

Note that, in general, running scripts in "the user's shell" is a bad idea. A system that runs shell script should be specifying the shell it expects, like /bin/sh or fish

The reason your attempt to use `bash -c` doesn't work is because your quoting is off. You're giving fish the command

```
bash -c ./bin/foo-script.sh ${BAR}
```

which means fish tries to do the expansion, because it's not quoted, and so it sees it as a syntax error and refuses the command.

This could work if you quoted the argument:

```
bash -c './bin/foo-script.sh ${BAR}'
```

because then, to fish, the `${BAR}` is in single-quotes, so it doesn't care about them.